# Ethereum wallet with running geth

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, datadir

I was trying to use the running geth, i used the wallet app to connect to this. nonetheless, i cannot seem to get the wallet to use the running instance of geth, even though i have the running instance of geth with

```
geth --rpc --datadir="mi/dir"
```

i am currently in windows10, using the wallet from https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases

thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**

this is normal because you are changine the datadir in geth, this causes an IPc change so that Ethereum wallet didn't see the geth running.

**The solution**
to your command run geth with the option `--ipcpath geth_path/geth.ipc` (you could choose a different path to indicate where the geth.ipc will be created)
and run your wallet (by draggin it to a cmd window) with `--rpc path/geth.ipc` (the same previous path)

*Info: The geth.ipc exists only when geth is running*

Comment: geth --datadir="d:\cryptocoins\ethereum" --fast --ipcpath "cryptocoins\geth.ipc

Comment: "Ethereum Wallet.exe" --rpc "cryptocoins\geth.ipc"

Comment: [2016-10-20 09:52:50.467] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connect to {"path":"cryptocoins\\geth.ipc"}
[2016-10-20 09:52:50.471] [WARN] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed, retrying after 1000ms...
[2016-10-20 09:52:51.473] [WARN] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed, retrying after 1000ms...
[2016-10-20 09:52:52.474] [WARN] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed, retrying after 1000ms...
[2016-10-20 09:52:53.469] [ERROR] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed (3000ms elapsed)

Comment: also tried with the absolute path d:\cryptocoins\geth.ipc